# Версии сайта с помощью .htaccess - помогите настроить реврайт

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite, регулярные-выражения

Вопрос в том, как удобно организовать работу с версиями сайта.
Допустим, имеем структуру сайта:

```
/styles/style-1/style.css
/styles/style-1/img/img-1.jpg
итд
```

И вот мы решили изменить версию сайта
Самое простое - удалить старые файлы и записать новые, но мы простых путей не ищем, ибо иногда нужно сделать откат (актуально на этапе тестирования)

Можно конечно создать новый стиль:

```
/styles/style-2/style.css
/styles/style-2/img/img-1.jpg
```

Если все ссылки грамотно организованы относительно корня директории со стилями, то проблем какбэ не возникнет.

Но идеальным вариантом, как мне кажется было бы настроить .htaccess таким образом, чтобы все запросы к папкам стиля переадресовывались **к актуальному стилю**. То есть:

запрос, например к таблице стиля **всегда** будет иметь вид:

```
www.name.ru/style/style.css
```

а физически файл будет находиться в каталоге /styles/style-1/ или /styles/style-2/

Тогда при переходе на новую версию скрипта достаточно будет указать эту версию в .htaccess

Собственно вопрос: **как настроить в этом случае .htaccess** ?

**Уточнение.** Кроме версий сайта могут быть и версии дизайна сайта. В этом случае структура каталогов будет чуть сложнее. Нужно разделить понятие стиля и понятие версии сайта. Допустим, стиль будет называться style а версия release. Тогда структура будет иметь вид:

```
/release-1/styles/style-base/style.css
/release-1/styles/style-base/img/img-1.jpg

пусть у нас будет ещё один стиль:

/release-1/styles/style-phone/style.css
/release-1/styles/style-phone/img/img-1.jpg
```

В общем, если кратко, то вопрос такой:

```
как превратить
/styles/style-base/style.css
/styles/style-base/img/img.jpg
/styles/style-base/*
в 
/release-1/styles/style-base/style.css 
/release-1/styles/style-base/img/img.jpg
/release-1/styles/style-base/*
```

пробовал написать так:

```
RewriteRule ^/styles/(.+)$  /release-1/styles/$1
```

но что-то не сработало. Мой htaccess в полном виде:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<Files "*.inc">
Deny from all
</Files>

Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine   on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$      /index.php
RewriteRule ^/styles/(.+)$  /release-1/styles/$1
```

Comment: **ГЕМОР!**

Comment: Решение благополучно найдено: нужно было изменить последовательность строк и добавить инструкцию. Ну и разумеется убрать открывающие слеши.

Я бы опубликовал решение, но на данном сайте это запрещено: типа мне нужно набрать каких-то очков, чтобы публиковать ответы на собственные вопросы... 

ps
Товарищ практолог, где вы видите гемор?

Comment: Решение благополучно найдено: нужно было **использовать git/svn/mercual**.  
// fixed

Comment: @пионэр, опубликуйте решение как комментарий (несколько комментариев, если не хватит места), а я сделаю ответом. Так можно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста. 
Искомую инструкцию нужно было прописывать первой и поставить флаг [L]

```
RewriteRule ^style(.+)$ /release-1/style$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  /index.php
```